Browser cached pages in Next js
Could you please advise me on the solution if you have encountered the problem?

Browser cached pages on production.
Incognito shows a fresh version of the interface.
When deploying another site - files are changed, other pages are shown

What tried to solve:

clean cache, cookies
do it through devtool - application tab
upload new updates
rename files through next.config setting
set cache-control header to max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
CloudFlare - enable developer mode, clean cache
use Netlify - clean cache there, redeploy.
replace netlify with vercel.

Already tried everything, it's not clear at all. Can you tell me what context is missing to understand the situation?

Didn't get the problem please describe clearly.
